# How to prevent the onProgressChanged event firing when setting the progress value of the seekbar from code?

Tags: android

If I set the progress or the max value of a seekbar from code then the onProgressChanged event gets fired. How to prevent this? I want the event to fire only when the user modifies the progress value from the UI by dragging the thumb of the seekbar.

Comment: Bit ugly but you could emulate this behavior with a boolean that you set to true if it's fired from the UI, back to false after it's done and false by default. Android is just wonky a lot of the time, I don't even bother thinking about it any more.

Comment: @G_V: But how do I know if it's fired from the UI?

Comment: I assume you have some sort of listener on the seekbar and that it causes the onProgressChanged to fire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your OnSeekBarChangeListener and [check boolean fromUser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html#onProgressChanged(android.widget.SeekBar,%20int,%20boolean))

Answer (score 0):

When Every time you are setting the value from code every time onProgressChanged event  fired. you can prevent it by giving the max value to seek bar into xml. and use a flag variable and put the code into that flag variable. e.g.

```
boolean flag = false;

onProgressChanged() {
    if(flag) {

---if you set the max bu code it skip the if body-------
    -------- do you code-----------------
    } 

    flag = true;
}
```